# Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

I am trying to install kubernetes with kubespray on my VPS servers. 
When I execute the playbook, I've got the following error message:

```
fatal: [k8s-m-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed."], "stdout": "Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked.\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked."]}
fatal: [k8s-m-2]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed."], "stdout": "Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked.\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked."]}
fatal: [k8s-n-1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed."], "stdout": "Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked.\r\n", "stdout_lines": ["Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked."]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried starting systemd-resolved.service ?

Comment: It says `Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked.`

Comment: is this ubuntu os ?Do you have this file /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service ?

Comment: Yes. The file exists.

Comment: what is the output of systemctl status systemd-resolved.service

Comment: `/lib/systemd/system# systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207051/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-arghya-sadhu).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
```